# Is site-to-site vpn hardware-dependent?

Tags: vpn, router, site-to-site-vpn

I was trying to set site to site VPN between google cloud VPC and on-premise network in my office. And I realized that the  Some router devices do not support configuring a site to site vpn.
For example, Netgear R7000 is a commercial router which doesn't support site-to-site vpn while Netgear BR500 is a business router that supports it.

Isn't site-to-site vpn on a software level? Why does it depend on hardware?

Answer (score 2):

Site to Site is a concept and means nothing more than a VPN that is routed - i.e. not "you get an IP address and use that" but "you get an IP address, and you route certain networks to it, not all traffic". There is not really any other definition - it depends on protocols. THAT SAID: while many routers do VPN, routers generally may lack in certain areas that the producer was ignorant to.

Netgear BR is not exactly a commercial grade router. Sorry. I would dare saying that a 50USD Mikrotik low end router has some more functionality. So, it really depends what you buy, what firmware you ahve etc. Simpple like that.

- It is on a software level.
- It does not depend on hardware, unless you talk of throughput - a low end router will not route 1gigabit/second with encryption.
- It totally depends on the firmware capabilities that the manufacturer considers necessary.

That sort of sums it up.